# Hide a specific row in product specification

Tags: product, tabs, magento2.1.5

I use a data content provider, I get product pictures and all information pushed into my server but some of the information I don't want to show up on the front end. If you want to take a look at my site see link below:
http://www.terabytecomponents.co.uk/cooler-master-cm-590-iii-white-3404.html

Click on the "**more information**" tab and if you scroll to the bottom there are 2 sections at the bottom named "**Sinch Search Cache**" & "**PDF Url**".

How can I remove these? 
It'll be across the whole catalog not just the link I have given.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the  **Sinch Search Cache** & **PDF Url** attributes in magento admin and from **StoreFront Properties** tab set property **Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront** to **NO**

Referesh Cache and check

Comment: Thanks. I already searched through that. I found PDF URL and removed it but Sinch Search Cache is not in the list.